# how to migrate from jive to sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, content-migration, migrationapi

I am investigating a way to migrate a complete site from Jive to a brand new SharePoint 2013 can some one give a direction ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automated way to do this

Your best option is

1. Create proper content & structure in SharePoint
2. Using [Jive SharePoint Connector](https://community.jivesoftware.com/blogs/jivespace/2012/10/11/sharepoint-connector-5011-now-available) move document from Jive to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

ThreeWill does this: https://threewill.com/services/jive-to-sharepoint-migrations/

Disclaimer: I work for ThreeWill.